# haproxy LB is showing as not secured after ssl enabled

Tags: haproxy

I got the .cer file from trusted CA source and created .pem file by using .cer and .key file. I have configured the haproxy to use the .pem file to enable ssl. But while accessing the haproxy frontend, it is still showing as "not secure".

please help me how can i change the site to "secured" https page.

Comment: You also need the intermediate certificate chain, after the "cer" file contents, inside the "pem."

Comment: Post your haproxy.conf redacting any sensitive information.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit file config use something like this in /etc/haproxy.cfg:

```
defaults
  log 127.0.0.1 local0

frontend https
       #jj mode http
        bind 0.0.0.0:443 ssl crt /[path]/test.pem
        reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https if { ssl_fc }
        #http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
        #option http-server-close
        #option forwardfor

        use_backend test_example_vn          if      { ssl_fc_sni test_example_vn }

frontend http
        bind *:80
        reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http
# Redirect domain
# This is redirect domain
# This is acl for all domain
        acl                 is_ test_example_vn            hdr_end(host)    -I     test.example.vn
# This is use_backend for all domain
        use_backend          test_example_vn         if             is_ test_example_vn
# This is backend for all domain

backend test_example_vn
cookie SRVNAME insert
  balance roundrobin
server http_082_5555 10.0.0.82:5555  check inter 5000 fastinter 1000 fall 1 rise 1 weight 1 maxconn 20
```

(10.0.0.82:5555 is :[IP Server]:[Port server web]). After you can restart ha proxy with command: `[root@test test]# service haproxy restart`

As per you can reads [haproxy_docs](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#5.1-crt)

Hope this helps for you!